# Mvvmcross launch another app programmatically

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross, appdelegate, openurl

I have a web app and I have setup URLScheme to open another app.

Idea is

1. At OpenUrl I insert records into sqlite database, that act as parameters to homeviewmodel (very first view).
2. and when homeviewmodel loads it will download data and save them to sqlite

But,
When they are switching, homeviewmodel already loaded and then openrl is called to insert paramaters to sqlite.

Basically I need parameters passed from first app be available to my another app before my very first view is hit.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I would just do it how reach platform does it.. Make an IStartAppService if you're wanting to call this from the core logic then implement these:

iOS using this <strike>Tutorial</strike> Basically you are just setting up a custom URL and can pass parameters too.

Android using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android) using LaunchIntent and the package name.

Comment: Link to tutorial in answer is dead.